# Manage environment variables with ansible

Tags: environment-variables, ansible

i need set the environment variable to build some app at startup, i use `vars` in the playbook file:

```
---
- hosts: all
  sudo: yes
  vars:
    build_env:
      VAR1: value1
      VAR2: value2
      VAR3: value3
```

And set with `environment` into task to build app

```
- name: Build app
  environment: "{{build_env}}"
  command: "{{ item }} chdir={{app1}}"
  with_items:
  - npm install
  - bower
  - gulp
```

Also i need add the same variables to `/etc/environment` but i would not replicate the same variables in another task, any idea?

Answer (score 0):

ansible-playbook -c local -i 127.0.0.1,  test.yml

test.yml:

```
---
- hosts: all
  sudo: yes
  vars:
    build_env:
      VAR1: value1
      VAR2: value2
      VAR3: value3

  tasks:
   - name: Build app
     environment: "{{build_env}}"
     shell: source /etc/environment; echo $VAR1 > ~/111
   - name: Build app
     environment: "{{build_env}}"
     shell:  source /etc/environment;env >> /root/111
```

Tested vars:

```
# cat /etc/environment
VAR1=2
export VALERY=x
export VAR2=ss
CCCCCCCCCC=xx
```

The result:

```
# cat  ~/111
value1
HOSTNAME=38b07f75ca28
SHLVL=1
HOME=/root
VALERY=x
_=/usr/local/bin/ansible-playbook
TERM=xterm
VAR1=value1
PATH=/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin
VAR2=value2
VAR3=value3
LANG=C
LC_MESSAGES=C
PWD=/
LC_ALL=C
```

Conclusiosn:

- `CCCCCCCCCC=xx` - wasn't exported
- The `environment:` override the variables, so you should export all
  variables in `/etc/environment`